# How to prevent a double enrollment in an event of the same participant.

Tags: civievent

We are using our CiviCRM to enroll participants from the office (not online), nonetheless the platform allows to enroll the same contact twice in the same event.  We are using CiviCRM on Druppal. I test the problem in the demo: http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/, and it also occurs in the demo.

Is there any mechanism to prevent double enrollment in an event?

Thanks in advance.

Please be aware, that this question is similar to other question, but the other was related to online enrollment, and my question is related to enrollment through the platform itself.

Answer (score 1):

An event has a profile and "Allow multiple participants".  If this is for a logged-in user, then it and you have unchecked allow multiple participants it should not let you participate in the event multiple times.  If you are using profile matching, then check the profile and see if the matching is set to duplicate or update.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. I check it, and it seems that this just applied to online registration. My problem is that an admin user could registered several times the same participant, and we want to prevent this. Do you know if there is something related to the event itself and not the online registration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:https://civicrm.org/blogs/spidersilk/understanding-civicrm-dedupe-rules

"Supervised rules, on the other hand, are rules that are automatically checked when an admin or staff member enters info into the back end of the site (i.e., the admin interface)."

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I am going to read it carefully, it seems that the solution for our case come in this way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I read it, and the information is useful, but it does not resolve the issue because it is more focused on the rule to avoid twice the same contact. Do you know if I could run the dedupe rule (unsupervised or supervised) based on the list of registered attendees to an event? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mari, It should resolve your issue. I tested on demo, by changing the Individual Rule "Email (reserved)" to Supervised and tried adding demo@example to Rain Forest event - system responded with: This contact has already been assigned to this event.

Comment: Thanks for testing the solution. Which based platform are you using?. I am using Drupal, I tested the solution as you describe it in demo with Drupal, but it is not working in the same way. That is rare.

Comment: I saw was going on. If I am in the contact, and select events and try to enroll this contact in an event that he/she is already enrolled, it works as you wrote it. But if you go to the menu events, choose register participant and look for the contact and the event allows you to re-enroll the contact that is already in the event list. This seems like a bug. Do you have any other idea / workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mari - looks like you have discovered a bug. Please file a bug report at: https://issues.civicrm.org  - not sure of a workaround, you may just need to ask users to register people by finding the user first, till the bug is fixed.

Comment: The bug may be related to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14865 - I will add a comment.

Comment: Perfect, I would ask the users to use this method in the meanwhile. Thanks a lot for your help.